# Use Google to generate a thumbnail of an image from a URL entirely online?

Tags: image, google-api, thumbnails

I have the need to create a large number of thumbnail images from a large online collection of images.  Unfortunately the images are huge, and I am looking to generate thumbnails for these images, without downloading each one just to process for the thumbnail, and without using a retail service.  Additionally, without creating any type of specialty server for just this task.

The solution seems so close.  Using the brute strength of Google to generate these thumbnails seems the right answer.

There are many articles online of how to use Google to generate thumbnails of their *sites*, this almost works for images but not quite.  For example, this article is very clever in its implementation:  http://phpotdel.ru/2012/03/02/skript-zagruzki-skrinshotov-s-google.html

Google does have the www.google.com/webpagethumbnail url, in which the url of any image can be included in the call, and it will return a thumbnail of the image.  The catch is that Google requires a hash tag at the end 'a'.

For example, this works:

https://www.google.com/webpagethumbnail?c=41&r=4&s=300&d=http://thenewswheel.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/2015-Hyundai-Genesis-11.jpg&a=AIYkKU9DavQuK0866UNbXJwkd03nPoZa-w

But this does not:

https://www.google.com/webpagethumbnail?c=41&r=4&s=300&d=http://thenewswheel.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/2015-Hyundai-Genesis-10.jpg&a=AIYkKU9DavQuK0866UNbXJwkd03nPoZa-w

The only difference being the image url is slightly different.

The Russian article linked above handles generating the hash code by first doing a generic web search for the web page it wants to generate snapshots of.  The hash codes included in the generic search work when included in the webpagethumbnail call.  In short, they trick Google into generating the hash, then use it to get the snapshot.  Cool... except it doesn't work for snapshots of *images*, just *web sites*.  The reason is that the generic search in order to get the hash code in the first place, doesn't work for images.

So, how was the above webpagethumbnail call that does work generated in the first place?  If you use goo.gl to shorten the image url, it happily presents you with a preview of the image, which uses the webpagethumbnail url above.

The problem with hacking together something using goo.gl to try to generate a thumbnail is that you need to sign in with your account to avoid the captcha.  This means that grandma Google has her eye on you, and will limit the number of goo.gl links you can generate in a day, I believe to something like 1000.  As a side note, I would love to know if Google ever plans on offering a premium service, in order to get past the limit.

The last tempting Google trick is to try to implement the Google 'Search by Image' API.  This does initially generate a thumbnail, but seems like overkill, and most likely would anger Mrs. Google.

Before responding, I am not asking how to make a thumbnail from an image.  I know how to do that.  I am asking if there is a way I can keep the entire process online, and do it essentially for free, without making Google crazy.  I have a ton of images online that need thumbnails generated (for the sake of this question, assume there will always me more and more, so the best way to handle this is to process them online).

I apologize if there is already a question out there that perhaps addresses this somehow, but I did a tremendous amount of searching, and found a lot of info on snapshots of sites, but not images (thumbnails).  I know this is a tough problem, and I don't really see a way of getting this done for free in a repeatable, none evil way, but that is why I am asking the question.

Thanks.